# Custom buttonBarButtonStyle

Tags: android, android-styles

In an APP i want an custom Text Color of Buttons because the Background which does no match quite well. All this is happening in an ButtonBar Style. I watched the Slides from Nick Butcher and read almost all SO questions there regarding this topic.

The below style changes the Text Color but the Button in not borderless. Im curious how this can be overridden without destroying the other attributes ?

```
<style name="CustomButtonBarButtonStyle" parent="android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

The APP uses API Level 15, so the general style is there.

Comment: Shouldn't the `android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle` be prefixed with a question mark?

Comment: Try it, the Project does not compile using an question mark

Comment: Can you post some layout code of how you referenced the style?